fscanf skips leading 7 from memory address
I would like to read lines from a file (memory traces from Valgrind). Each line in the file
is either of the I 0400d7d4,8 or  M 0421c7f0,4 format (i.e. white space at beginning of the line). When the code below reads the file and steps through the file, memory addresses starting with a leading 7 are output without the 7, i.e. 7ff000398 becomes ff000398. Leading zeroes are also omitted/skipped, but that is not an issue. However, given 7ff000398 and ff000398 are different locations (numbers), and I need to partition the address for further processing.

The following file content reproduces the problem.

S 7ff000398,8
S 7ff000390,8


Output:

Parsed line: # 0. Operation: S, address:     ff000398, size: 8
Parsed line: # 1. Operation: S, address:     ff000390, size: 8  

// some logic before this
FILE * pFile;
    pFile = fopen(tracefile, "r");
    if (!pFile) {
        fprintf(stderr, "unable to open %s\n", tracefile);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    char operation_id;
    unsigned address;
    int size;
    // Line is of format " M 0x3242,4" or "I 0x324234,4"
    const char *format = " %c %16x,%d";
    int i = 0;
    while (fscanf(pFile, format, &operation_id, &address, &size) > 0) {
        printf("Parsed line: # %d. Operation: %c, address: %16x, size: %d\n", i, operation_id, address, size);
        i++;
    }

The output of this becomes:
Parsed line: # 0. Operation: S, address:     ff000398, size: 8
Parsed line: # 1. Operation: S, address:     ff000390, size: 8

I've tried different formats to no avail (e.g. adding 0x before. Regardless of the right approach  (i.e. don't use fscanf, etc), there must be a conceptual misunderstanding I possess about how fscanf works.

It should be worth noting that you have discovered a known problem with the *scanf() family functions: invalid numerical input (including overflow) produces Undefined Behavior. Your implementation is nice enough to simply lose the extra bits instead of doing something worse. I personally recommend not using *scanf() functions in production code.

You are reading addresses; use the type uintptr_t and macros SCNXPTR and PRIXPTR from <inttypes.h>.

The address variable you are attempting to put the value in has type unsigned, and that is 32 bits in your C implementation, which is insufficient to hold the 35-bit value 7ff00039816.
Use a different type, possibly unsigned long long with a %llx conversion specification.

given known vagaries of *scanf functions and the variability of your input, i suggest using strsep C function to parse your input, its way more flexible,
trivial example shown:
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if ( 3 != argc ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s filename delimiters\n", argv[0]);
        exit(-1);
    }
    
    FILE *fp = fopen( argv[1], "r" );
    char *elem;
    char record[2048];
    char *rptr;

    while( fgets( record, sizeof(record), fp ) != NULL )
    {
        record[strlen(record)-1]='\0';
        fprintf(stdout, "read [%s]\t", record );
        rptr=record;
        for (int j = 1; ( elem = strsep( &rptr, argv[2] ) ); j++)
            fprintf(stdout, "elem[%s]\t", elem );

        fprintf(stdout, "\n" );
    }
    fclose(fp);
    exit(0);
}

./a.out sample.dat ' ,'
read [S 7ff000398,8]    elem[S] elem[7ff000398] elem[8] 
read [ S 7ff000390,8]   elem[]  elem[S] elem[7ff000390] elem[8] 
read [V x7ff000r400,9]  elem[V] elem[x7ff000r400]   elem[9] 

